# Django overwrite applications urls

Tags: django, url

I have a project with three applications installed. The first (photologue) is working fine, but I'm having problems with the last two. My urls.py file in the Django site looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib import admin
from funvisis.users.models import FVISUser
admin.site.register(FVISUser)
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^photologue/', include('photologue.urls')),
    (r'^inspeccionespuentes/', include('funvisis.bridgeinspections.urls')),
    (r'^inspeccionesedificios/', include('funvisis.buildinginspections.urls')),
    )
```

The urls.py file on both of my applications looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from .admin import admin_site
from .views import csv_view
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^csv/(?P<models_url>\w+)/', csv_view),
                       (r'', include(admin_site.urls),
                      )
```

The problem arise when I try to reach the url "^inspeccionesedificios/", since there is no link to add a new buildinginspection and the link to list all the inspections is formed as "http://127.0.0.1:8000/inspeccionespuentes/buildinginspections/" (note how it starts with "inspeccionespuentes" rather than "inspeccionesedificios").

If I change the order of the patterns in the Django site from:

```
    (r'^inspeccionespuentes/', include('funvisis.bridgeinspections.urls')),
    (r'^inspeccionesedificios/', include('funvisis.buildinginspections.urls')),
```

to:

```
    (r'^inspeccionesedificios/', include('funvisis.buildinginspections.urls')),
    (r'^inspeccionespuentes/', include('funvisis.bridgeinspections.urls')),
```

results in the same behaviour but with the problem in "inspeccionespuentes".

I have recently migrated from Django 1.3 to Django 1.4 and this problem ain't appeared before the migration. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: can't get your question clearly

Comment: why didn't you use the standard/common way of writting  `urlpatterns` in your apps? I think It will be more easy to understand the urls. Also check your views(), probably you are redirecting ^inspeccionesedificios/ to somewhere else or something is wrong.

Comment: And why are you adding the admin URLs to both includes as well as the main one? That makes no sense. They only belong in the root one.

Comment: machaku, what's the standard/common way? Where can I read about it?